# Why Dojo grid.refresh is making another server call?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

We are using dojo JsonRest. Whenever we need to refresh the grid with new data, dojo is firing two server calls.

Below is the code.

```
var MyJsonRest = declare(JsonRest, {
   get: function(id, options) {
       return this.inherited(
           arguments, 
           [id, lang.mixin(this.headers, options)]);
   }
});

myDataStore = MyJsonRest({
    target: someurl,
   headers: { 
      'moduleUName': somemodulename
   },
   idAttribute: "id",
       query: function(query, options) {
          // some other code                    
      }                   

});

myDataStore.get("", { paramName: paramValue }).then(function(result) { // this fires a request to server
  gridObj.refresh(); // this fires same request 2nd time to the server
  // if the gridObj.refresh() is commented out, then the grid does not displayes the new data.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the Grid to detect changes in the store without triggering the refresh, you should wrap your JsonRest store with the dojo.store.Observable.  Any updates to the store will then be auto updated in the grid.

```
myCacheDataStore = new Cache(myDataStore, new Memory({});
myObservableDataStore = new Observable(myCacheDataStore)
```

You should be able to pass myObservableDataStore in place of myDataStore.

To update or refresh the grid you can change the target url or update the headers in myDataStore directly and call grid.refresh.  I have not tested with the updating of headers, but my example changes the target url from

```
/rest/users/
```

to

```
/rest/users/?username=jdoe
```

and the grid updates fine.

```
myDataStore.target = '/rest/users/?username=jdoe'
```

or maybe

```
myDataStore.headers[paramName] = paramValue
```

since your MyJsonRest store mixin the options provided into "get" into the headers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I wrap above code in the observable?

Comment: Sorry for the vague answer.  I've added a code snippet, this is assuming that you have require the dojo/store/Observable

Comment: I tried what u said. But its not working. No errors. But now it doesn't display the grid with the initial data also.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the dojox.grid.DataGrid widget?  If so, are you wrapping the myObservableDataStore in dojo.data.ObjectStore?

Comment: What I've done in the past is wrapped the JsonRest in a few different store to achieve the auto-update.  I've updated the code snippet to reflect the changes.

Comment: Ok, no need for the dojo.data.ObjectStore then.  Does the cache store help?

Comment: I tried with my working code and without using the Cache store seems fine.  I also don't use the get method in the store though.  Instead, I update the target url of the JsonRest store to include the new query parameters and just call the grid refresh.  I believe the get method simply just pulls the item matching the given ID.

Comment: Thanks. Its working now after removing store.get call and just updating the header in the store and then calling refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have a far more straightforward answer than the accepted answer (as evidenced by a comment near the end of it).

You're calling `get` on your store, then calling `grid.refresh()` inside the success handler for that call.  Since you're using a server-based store, `get` is going to fire one request itself.  The grid is going to fire another request (via the store's `query` method) to get a list of items to populate itself with.

It's unclear from your example if there's another reason why you're initially calling `get`, but calling store methods directly will not populate widgets like the grid - widgets access the store directly themselves.